# How to troubleshoot and resolve 'Session store not set on request' error in Laravel on Fedora Linux?

Tags: php, laravel, fedora

## Session store not set on request,Laravel (Fedora Linux)

I'm encountering an issue where the session store is not being set on my Laravel request.

when I make a request, I receive an error message stating "Session store not set on request.

Here are some details about my setup:

- I am using Laravel framework [10.11.0].
- I have properly configured the session driver in my .env file (e.g., SESSION_DRIVER=file).
- I have verified that the session files are being created in the designated storage directory.

Can someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot and resolve this "Session store not set on request" problem? What could be causing this issue and how can I ensure the session store is properly set on the request?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Despite these configurations, I am still unable to set the session store on the request. I have tried various approaches, including clearing the cache, regenerating session keys, and adjusting session middleware. However, the issue persists.

Comment: Could you show the code or the error exactly? We cannot picture what you are trying to say in plain text.

Comment: show the actual error message and perhaps stack trace ... my guess would be something is trying to access the session via the request too early in the lifecycle of the application